# ASP .NET Core Web Server console output not visible in VS for .NET Core 2.2

Tags: visual-studio, asp.net-core, iis-express

I created a .NET Core 2.2 web application project in VS 2017 and the `ASP.NET Core Web Server` option from the console output is not visible when the application runs with `IIS Express`.

By .NET Core 2.1 web application projects this option is there and it is showing the output without any problems.

Comment: Might be related to https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2018/Dec/31/Dont-let-ASPNET-Core-Default-Console-Logging-Slow-your-App-down

Comment: @LexLi not sure about this. The problem is that I don not have any output at all.

Comment: try the solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40148660/how-to-get-a-console-output-in-asp-net-core-with-iis-express

Comment: Show some screen shots to tell what exactly you are looking for.

Comment: @MustafaSaeed not the solution but the comment of Ilya Chernomordik was very helpful. Indeed I had to select the start up project in the profile instead of IIS Express and the I could see the logs.

Comment: @Stam happy to help! :)

Comment: I am not seeing the console.  Chose the profile as Stam says above.  I really want to see this as it helps immensely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you have to right-click on Project->Properties.
Then on the right side menu to select "Debug".
In Web Server Settings find "Hosting Model" and select "Out of process"[image]

Answer (score 1):

The simplest option is to change your currently selected debugger run option (the dropdown with the green "play" button / F5) from IIS, to the name of your project (e.g. so that "FooWebApp" shows up now in the dropdown). This way the browser will still open like it was before, but the console window will start showing as well.

On the other route with Tuvia's answer above (thanks!), it's actually `Properties/launchSettings.json` which stores / determines these actions. There you can also set `"launchBrowser": false` if wanted, or if you want to change if the console window opens, within `"IIS Express"` profile, manually add: `"ancmHostingModel": "OutOfProcess"` (or else set to `InProcess`).